# Difference in meaning of . $ # in coffee script?

Tags: coffeescript

What is the difference between `. $ #` in coffee script?
Could someone explain me it clearly, or point to brief info about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#` is the comment marker

`.` normally connects an object to a property.  This is normal Javascript behavior.  `myobj['aproperty']` is the same as `myobj.aproperty`.

`$` does not have special meaning.  But `jquery` often loaded under that name.  Again, just a typical Javascript usage.  Nothing special about Coffeescript usage.